# Unable to add an instance of HandleInterceptorAdapter

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, interceptor

I am trying to intercept every HTTP request that comes into my Spring Boot application.
For this I have a LoggingInterceptor as follows:

```
@Component
public class LoggingInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingInterceptor.class);

public LoggingInterceptor() {
    super();
    logger.debug("LoggingInteceptor constructor");
}
@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
    logger.debug("LoggingInteceptor: Intercepted  " + request.getRequestURI());
            return true;

}
```

}

Then, I have an @Configuration class for adding the interceptor to the registry as follows:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class LoggingConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
@Autowired
LoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor;

public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry){
    registry.addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor);
}

}
```

However, I just cannot see any of the logger statements. Is there something more I need to do to get this going?

Comment: I have put a breakpoint in `registry.addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor);` but the breakpoint is never hit. Does this mean that Spring isn't loading the interceptor? What should I do to make Spring load it?

Comment: Remove `@EnableWebMvc`, your interceptor doesn't need `@Component` so simply construct a new one in the `addInterceptors` method. Next make sure that Spring Boot is actually scanning the package your `@Configuration` class is in.

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration looks fine. Also `registry.addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor);` call would fail if interceptor would be null, therefore it seems to be correctly wired.

Therefore I would verify:

1. if DEBUG level us enabled in logging framework
2. If both classes are included into your Spring context at all (put breakpoint addInterceptors method and start app)

**EDIT:**

OK, so comment confirmed that you your problem is my first point.
You need to find out logging configuration file (e.g. log4j.properties, log4j,xml or logback.xml) and change log level from INFO to DEBUG there.

Comment: I have put a breakpoint in `registry.addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor);` but the breakpoint is never hit. Does this mean that Spring isn't loading the interceptor? What should I do to make Spring load it?

Comment: When you send a request belonging to your servlet, breakpoint should be hit if you have everything configured correctly. Post more relevant code and servlet configuration + URL you are using.

Comment: Finally, I found out why the breakpoints weren't being hit. The "Skip all breakpoints" option had been set in Eclipse!! I wasted so many hours on this. However, `logger.debug` statements are still not printing, but `logger.info` is. What should I do for this?